# is there anyway to start reactjs after build bundle?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I built my reactjs website with these command:

```
npm run build
```

After that, build folder is generated. To start server:

```
   npm install -g serve
    serve -s build
```

I want to run my react app background. Since i have no file *.js like:

```
 nodemon lib/index.js --exec babel-node --presets=es2015,stage-2
```

from [How to use nodemon in npm scripts to build and start scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828979/how-to-use-nodemon-in-npm-scripts-to-build-and-start-scripts)

Any hint would be appreciated from my heart.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Have you tried using just a semi colon to chain your commands?

Comment: what is it,please? I'm really have no idea about what you meant.

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/chaining-operators-in-linux-with-practical-examples/#:~:text=Chaining%20of%20Linux%20commands%20means,them%20from%20the%20terminal%20directly.

ex: npm install; node run build;